# How to merge several small components with nearest larger components?

Tags: image-processing

I am doing a segmentation of some objects in a 3D image `img3d`:
[image]

image-stack can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nsszin69z5sfzs2/AABeN2IOV4CwheJkOWq0G34na?dl=0

I wish to divide the image into five morphological components (equal to the objects seen in the stack).

I follow the procedure:

```
morph = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize@img3d,CornerNeighbors -> True];
morph // Colorize
```

the image i get at the end is shown below (viewed from two angles):

[image]

the segmentation seems ok when viewed from the top, however, not too good when viewed from the bottom; one reason is because these tiny components (specks) can be merged with the nearest bigger components!

[image]

One scheme i can think of uses `Nearest` (constructed from the centroids of the five bigger components) and `ReplacePart` to re-label small components in `morph` with the label of the nearest big component. The method proves to be very slow.

Is there an efficient way to merge the smaller components (specks) with bigger components?

Comment: How to get your `img3d`

Comment: @yode just added the link

Comment: Quickly fix your code.`Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[
  Closing[DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize@img3d, 50], 1]]]`

Comment: @yode the problem is even if i use your current code and change 50 to say 1 we have the same problem. Also, will closing artificially interpolate?

Comment: @yode i removed the `DeleteSmallComponents` from the question.

Comment: @Rahul the 50 is part of DeleteSmallComponents. I believe it means that a particle of size less than 50 will be removed or deleted from the 3D image.

Comment: I see, I misread the 50 to be an argument for `Closing` instead of `DeleteSmallComponents`. Here is something that seems to help: `Colorize@MorphologicalComponents[Binarize@Opening[Closing[img3d, 2], 2], CornerNeighbors -> True]`